# "Table Doesn't Exist" error using Google Drive spreadsheets in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets

I have followed Daneil Kehoe's guide for using Google Drive spreadsheets to make an online database for a Rails app, but I'm having trouble. I encountered this problem when trying to write an iterator for the 'index' view of a 'Notes' controller. I got this error:

```
undefined method `each' for Note(Table doesn't exist):Class
```

with this code:

```
<tbody>
  <% Note.each do |note|%>
    <tr>
      <th><%= note.title %></th>
      <th><%= note.contents %></th> 
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Here is my 'note.rb' file where the Spreadsheet configuration info is

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_no_table
    column :title, :string
    column :contents, :string
    def update_spreadsheet
        connection = GoogleDrive.login(ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"], ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"])
        ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('central-app-notes')
        if ss.nil?
        ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('central-app-notes')
        end
        ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    last_row = 1 + ws.num_rows
    ws[last_row, 1] = Time.new
    ws[last_row, 2] = self.title
    ws[last_row, 3] = self.content
    ws.save
    end
end
```

I am using obscured login details with the Figaro gem that are stored in my application.yml file. I am pretty sure the google drive spreadsheet configuration isn't working because I can't find a single spreadsheet in my Google Drive (yes, I'm logged into the right account).

Here's my 'index' action in the NotesController:

```
def index
        @note = Note.all
```

end

If you want to poke around the project you can go here: 
https://github.com/MaxPleaner/someapp
To get to the error in question, click the first 'Notes' link on the root page.

Comment: This is the error that Rails gives when the associated SQL table doesn't exist. I can see the table in your schema file. In what context are you executing this? Have you checked the database?

Comment: I am trying to make a google drive spreadsheet that functions as a database. Unfortunately, though, the spreadsheet isn't being created. I'm not sure why, as I followed the instructions from a tutorial.

Comment: Is the tutorial available online anywhere?  Looking at the tableless gem, it's not obvious how to retrieve the information that you store.  I tried changing your `Note.each` call in the view to use `@note` that's defined in the controller, but the tableless overrides #find_by_sql, causing that to fail.

Comment: Sorry, by "context", I meant are you executing the code in the Rails console, running it under RSpec or some other test framework or running it in an app?  Your `schema.rb` looks fine, but have you checked the appropriate database for the existence of the table `notes`?

Comment: @arbylee here is a link to the chapter https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0eEpdCGkSQQRkxFaFBOTzBZeVE/edit?usp=sharing  it's less than 10 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, linking to the tutorial helped.  So with this gem, you no longer access your data through the ActiveRecord methods.

Instead of doing `Note.each` to access your notes, you need to manually pull them from the spreadsheet.  So in your controller, do something like:

```
def index
  connection = GoogleDrive.login(ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"], ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"])
  spreadsheet = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('central-app-notes')
  @ws = spreadsheet.worksheets[0]
end
```

And in your view, access your data via the @ws variable.  I'm not familiar with this google spreadsheet gem, but it looks like you can access your data with `@ws.cells` or you can get a google spreadsheet object with `@ws.spreadsheet`

You'll have to play around with the @ws object and see what data is most useful for you (explore the methods available via `@ws.methods`).  This should get you past your current hump though

Answer (score 0):

Looking in your app, you need to put your configurations for google_drive gem in your config/application.yml for the figaro gem

```
GMAIL_USERNAME: Your_Username
GMAIL_PASSWORD: Your_Password
```

I know in your question you said that you did, but looking through your app https://github.com/MaxPleaner/someapp and there is no application.yml in your config folder.

Also, in your notes/index.html.erb view, I would use @notes instead of Note because you're passing in that instance variable from your controller.

```
<tbody>
  <% @notes.each do |note|%>
    <tr>
      <th><%= note.title %></th>
      <th><%= note.contents %></th> 
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you can look at the github page now and i included the application.yml file

Comment: Thanks, though you might want to put that back in .gitignore! I just was making sure you had it, I was looking through the app, and found something else that might be causing the errors and added it to the answer

Comment: it's all good, i thought about that though, it's pretty much a throwaway account so its all good.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working. I guess I can just try to NOT use google spreadsheets as a database and that might work

Comment: Same error as before? `undefined method 'each' for Note(Table doesn't exist):Class`